# Where is "cluster_name" defined in Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

[Hadoop Cluster Setup](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html) document has the insturuciton:

> The first time you bring up HDFS, it must be formatted. Format a new distributed filesystem as hdfs:
> `[hdfs]$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs namenode -format <cluster_name>`

Please advise where `cluster_name` is defined or explained, as it looks there is no definition in the document.

Comment: You can ignore that argument if you've setup your core-site.xml file correctly, as specified on that page

Answer (score 1):

You can check core-site.xml file for the default HDFS address.

```
    <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://THE_NAME_HERE</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
```